# Hide hovered submenu when another one is selected JQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, submenu

How do I hide a submenu when another one is selected when the mouse hovers over it?

In the example below, the Europe and Africa submenus stay on top of each other. I want to be able to hide each one as soon as another continent link is hovered.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//Abre menu #Eur1
$('#Europe').hover(function(){
    $('#Eur').show("blind");
    $('#Asi').hide('blind');
    $('#Afr').hide('blind');
},function(){
    $('#Eur').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).hide("blind");
    });
});

//Abre menu #Afr1
$('#Africa').hover(function(){
    $('#Afr').show("blind");
    $('#Eur').hide('blind');
    $('#Asi').hide('blind');
},function(){
    $('#Afr').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).hide("blind");
        
    });
});
  
//Abre menu #Asi1
$('#Asia').hover(function(){
    $('#Asi').show("blind");
    $('#Eur').hide('blind');
    $('#Afr').hide('blind');
},function(){
    $('#Asi').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).hide("blind");         
    });
});

});
```

```css
body,html {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    max-width: 100%;    
}

        
/* Estilos da navegação principal`*/  
#container {       
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
width: 100%;

}

.nav {
cursor: default;
display: inline-block; 
height: 125px;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
width: auto;
  
    
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -ms-display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.nav,
.nav a,
.nav ul,
.nav li,
.nav div {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav > li {
   
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.nav > li > a {   
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
    padding: 0 20px;    
    z-index: 510;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition:  all .3s ease;
}

.nav li:hover a {
    background-color:  black;
    color: white;
} 

.nav > li > div {    
    background: white;    
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100vw;   
    z-index: 500;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    transition: all .3s ease .3s;
}

.nav li:hover > div {
    opacity: .7;
    visibility: visible ;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .nav-column {
    /*color: black;*/
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;    
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 8%;
}

.nav .nav-column:first-child {
    margin-left: 15%;
}

.nav li div .nav-column a {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
    font-size: 0.9em; 
    font-weight: 500;   
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.nav li div .nav-column:hover a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition:  all .3s ease;
} 

#Eur {
    background: black;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: .7;
    top: 145px;
    width: 100%;  
    z-index: 660;
}

#Eur ul {    
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
}

#Eur ul:first-child {
     margin-left: 15%;
}

#Eur ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2%;
}

#Eur ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}

#Eur ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#Afr {
    background: black;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: .7;
    text-align: center;
    top: 145px;
    width: 100%;  
    z-index: 660;
}

#Afr ul {
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
}

#Afr ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2%;
    text-align: left;
}

#Afr ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
    
}

#Afr ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#Asi {
    background: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d1a559;
    border-top: 2px solid #d1a559;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: .7;
    top: 145px;
    width: 100%;  
    z-index: 660;
}

#Asi ul {    
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
}

#Asi ul:first-child {
     margin-left: 15%;
}

#Asi ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2%;
}

#Asi ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}

#Asi ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1a559;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    
             
        <div id="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>                 
                <li>
                    <a href="#">destinations <b class="caret">&triangledown;</b></a>
                    <div id="subMenu">                         
                    <div class="nav-column">                         
                        <a href="#" id="Europe">Europe</a>                           
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-column">                       
                        <a href="#" id="Africa">Africa</a>                         
                    </div>                         
                    <div class="nav-column">                      
                        <a href="" id="Asia">Asia</a>                          
                    </div>                        
                     <div class="nav-column">                      
                         <a href="">Oceania</a>                          
                    </div>                         
                     <div class="nav-column">                      
                         <a href="">North America</a>                          
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="nav-column">                      
                        <a href="">South America</a>                          
                    </div>                    
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>         
    </div>
        
        
        <div id="Eur" class="active">  
               <ul id="Eur1">
                        <li> <a href="#">Austria</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Belgium</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Bosnia & Herzegovina</a> </li> 
                        <li> <a href="#">Bulgaria</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Croatia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Czech Republic</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Denmark</a> </li> 
                        <li> <a href="#">Estonia</a> </li>
               </ul>
               <ul id="Eur2">                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Finland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">France</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Germany</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Greece</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Hungary</a> </li>                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Italy</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Latvia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Lithuania</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Luxembourg</a> </li>
               </ul>
               <ul id="Eur3">                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Macedonia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Montenegro</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Norway</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Poland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Portugal</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Roménia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Russia</a> </li>                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Serbia</a> </li>
               </ul>
               <ul id="Eur4">                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Slovakia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Slovenia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Spain</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Sweden</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Switzerland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">The Netherlands</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Turkey</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Ukraine</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">UK and Ireland</a> </li>                
                    </ul>
                </div>
        <div id="Afr" class="active">
            <ul id="Afr1">
                        <li> <a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Morocco</a> </li>                                                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Namibia</a></li>                            
                        <li> <a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Tunisia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Zambia</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
  <div id="Asi" class="active">
            <ul id="Asi1">
           <li> <a href="#">Bangladesh</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">Cambodia</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">China</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">India</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="#">Indonesia</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">Japan</a></li>  
           <li> <a href="#">Laos</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="Asi2">
            <li> <a href="#">Myanmar</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Nepal</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Uzbekistan</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Vietnam</a> </li>
            </ul>  
        </div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class to the submenus. For exmaple: `sub`. Then use `$('.sub').stop().hide("blind");` in every hover event to first hide any visible submenu. By the way, your code and html is a mess. Learn to use classes and how to reuse your code to make a proper nav.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

//Abre menu #Eur1
$('#Europe').hover(function(){
   $('.sub').stop().hide("blind");
   $('#Eur').show("blind");
},function(){
    $('#Eur').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).hide("blind");
    });
});

//Abre menu #Afr1
$('#Africa').hover(function(event){
    $('.sub').stop().hide("blind");
    $('#Afr').show("blind");
    event.stopPropagation;
},function(){
    $('#Afr').mouseleave(function(event){
        $(this).hide("blind");
        event.stopPropagation;
    });
});
});
```

```css
body,html {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    max-width: 100%;    
}

        
/* Estilos da navegação principal`*/  
#container {       
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
width: 100%;

}

.nav {
cursor: default;
display: inline-block; 
height: 125px;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
width: auto;
  
    
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -ms-display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.nav,
.nav a,
.nav ul,
.nav li,
.nav div {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav > li {
   
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.nav > li > a {   
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
    padding: 0 20px;    
    z-index: 510;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition:  all .3s ease;
}

.nav li:hover a {
    background-color:  black;
    color: white;
} 

.nav > li > div {    
    background: white;    
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100vw;   
    z-index: 500;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
    transition: all .3s ease .3s;
}

.nav li:hover > div {
    opacity: .7;
    visibility: visible ;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .nav-column {
    /*color: black;*/
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;    
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 8%;
}

.nav .nav-column:first-child {
    margin-left: 15%;
}

.nav li div .nav-column a {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
    font-size: 0.9em; 
    font-weight: 500;   
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.nav li div .nav-column:hover a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none; 
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition:  all .3s ease;
} 

#Eur {
    background: black;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: .7;
    top: 145px;
    width: 100%;  
    z-index: 660;
}

#Eur ul {    
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
}

#Eur ul:first-child {
     margin-left: 15%;
}

#Eur ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2%;
}

#Eur ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}

#Eur ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#Afr {
    background: black;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: .7;
    text-align: center;
    top: 145px;
    width: 100%;  
    z-index: 660;
}

#Afr ul {
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
}

#Afr ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2%;
    text-align: left;
}

#Afr ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
    
}

#Afr ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    
             
        <div id="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>                 
                <li>
                    <a href="#">destinations <b class="caret">&triangledown;</b></a>
                    <div id="subMenu">                         
                    <div class="nav-column">                         
                        <a href="#" id="Europe">Europe</a>                           
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-column">                       
                        <a href="#" id="Africa">Africa</a>                         
                    </div>                         
                    <div class="nav-column">                      
                        <a href="">Asia</a>                          
                    </div>                        
                     <div class="nav-column">                      
                         <a href="">Oceania</a>                          
                    </div>                         
                     <div class="nav-column">                      
                         <a href="">North America</a>                          
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="nav-column">                      
                        <a href="">South America</a>                          
                    </div>                    
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>         
    </div>
        
        
        <div id="Eur" class="sub">  
               <ul id="Eur1">
                        <li> <a href="#">Austria</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Belgium</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Bosnia & Herzegovina</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Bulgaria</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Croatia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Czech Republic</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Denmark</a> </li> 
                        <li> <a href="#">Estonia</a> </li>
               </ul>
               <ul id="Eur2">                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Finland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">France</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Germany</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Greece</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Hungary</a> </li>                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Italy</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Latvia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Lithuania</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Luxembourg</a> </li>
               </ul>
               <ul id="Eur3">                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Macedonia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Montenegro</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Norway</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Poland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Portugal</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Roménia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Russia</a> </li>                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Serbia</a> </li>
               </ul>
               <ul id="Eur4">                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Slovakia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Slovenia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Spain</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Sweden</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Switzerland</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">The Netherlands</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Turkey</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Ukraine</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">UK and Ireland</a> </li>                
                    </ul>
                </div>
        <div id="Afr" class="sub">
            <ul id="Afr1">
                        <li> <a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Morocco</a> </li>                                                        
                        <li> <a href="#">Namibia</a></li>                            
                        <li> <a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Tunisia</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Zambia</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm having performance issues when rendering each menu. For example, if i keep hovering from Europe to Africa and vice-versa, each menu will stop at the previous height where i changed to another link. Reading the Jquery documentation, it seems the stop() method can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a class to each of the submenus and then hiding all of that class before showing the selected ID on each new hover:

**UPDATED**:

answer adjusted with an alternative JS function to cycle through and hide all submenu's unless it's one that's named by menu data attribute in the HTML. Note the new `data-sub='Eur'` attributes in the 'nav-column' html divs, these point to the submenu ID names.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.nav-column').mouseover(function() {
    var submenu = $('a', this).data('sub'); // get the pointing to 'data-sub' id name
    $('.retract').each(function() { // cycle through all the submenus
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.attr('id') === submenu) {
        $this.show('blind'); // if it's the point to submenu then show
      } else {
        $this.hide('blind'); // otherwise hide
      }
    });
  });

  $('.nav-column').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.retract').hide("blind");
  });


  //Abre menu #Eur1
  /*  $('#Europe').hover(function() {
      $('.retract').hide("blind");
      $('#Eur').show("blind");
    }, function() {
      $('#Eur').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).hide("blind");
      });
    });

    //Abre menu #Afr1
    $('#Africa').hover(function(event) {
      $('.retract').hide("blind");
      $('#Afr').show("blind");
      event.stopPropagation;
    }, function() {
      $('#Afr').mouseleave(function(event) {
        $(this).hide("blind");
        event.stopPropagation;
      });
    }); */





});
```

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* Estilos da navegação principal`*/

#container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav {
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 125px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: auto;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-display: -ms-flexbox;
}
.nav,
.nav a,
.nav ul,
.nav li,
.nav div {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav > li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 20px;
  z-index: 510;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.nav li:hover a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.nav > li > div {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 500;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease .5s;
  transition: all .3s ease .3s;
}
.nav li:hover > div {
  opacity: .7;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav .nav-column {
  /*color: black;*/
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 8%;
}
.nav .nav-column:first-child {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
.nav li div .nav-column a {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav li div .nav-column:hover a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
#Eur {
  background: black;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: .7;
  top: 145px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 660;
}
#Eur ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
}
#Eur ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
#Eur ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2%;
}
#Eur ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
}
#Eur ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
#Afr {
  background: black;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: .7;
  text-align: center;
  top: 145px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 660;
}
#Afr ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
}
#Afr ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: left;
}
#Afr ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#Afr ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>


  <div id="container">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">destinations <b class="caret">&triangledown;</b></a>
        <div id="subMenu">
          <div class="nav-column">
            <a href="#" id="Europe" data-sub="Eur">Europe</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="nav-column">
            <a href="#" id="Africa" data-sub="Afr">Africa</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="nav-column">
            <a href="">Asia</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="nav-column">
            <a href="">Oceania</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="nav-column">
            <a href="">North America</a> 
          </div>
          <div class="nav-column">
            <a href="">South America</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#about">about</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="Eur" class="retract">
    <ul id="Eur1">
      <li> <a href="#">Austria</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Belgium</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Bosnia & Herzegovina</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Bulgaria</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Croatia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Czech Republic</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Denmark</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Estonia</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="Eur2">
      <li> <a href="#">Finland</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">France</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Germany</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Greece</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Hungary</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Italy</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Latvia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Lithuania</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Luxembourg</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="Eur3">
      <li> <a href="#">Macedonia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Montenegro</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Norway</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Poland</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Portugal</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Roménia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Russia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Serbia</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="Eur4" class="retract">
      <li> <a href="#">Slovakia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Slovenia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Spain</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Sweden</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Switzerland</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">The Netherlands</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Turkey</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Ukraine</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">UK and Ireland</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Afr" class="retract">
    <ul id="Afr1">
      <li> <a href="#">Egypt</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Morocco</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Namibia</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">South Africa</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Tunisia</a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Tanzania</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Zambia</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks. As i answered below to Miro, i'm having performance issues also. Guess i need to find another method for this.

Comment: Have revised the answer to remove the `.show()` functions from the hide 'on complete' functions to help it behave a little quicker

Comment: Somehow, when i use your solution, when hovering for example the link for the Africa menu, the previous menu displays behind the Africa menu. That happens with every menu...the Europe, Africa and Asia menu even stack on top of each other. So the solution i found was to use the hide() method to each menu in the hover like this: $('$Eur').hide('blind'); You can see the updated code. With this, things work perfectly well but that implies writing more lines of code. I was advised to create a function that hides each menu and call it in the hover function but couldn't work out how to do it.

Comment: updated. this method effectively applies hide and show appropriately to each sub-menu as requested. It uses `mouseleave` and `mouseover` instead of hover, but you may have different results if you readapt for `hover`. note the adjustment to the HTML.